# Database ResourceException

Tags: java, sqlexception

We are facing application slowness issue frequently. When we search the logs, we could see that:

```
java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException
IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources
```

Our connection pool size - 20 
How to resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two possible reason: 1) in your code you are not returning the connections properly to the pool 2) you have so many concurrent requests that the pool simply is too small

Answer (score 0):

Check connection leakage in your code. And also in code find if any db connection you haven't closed, if it is open.

Answer (score 0):

Options are:

- Check if result sets/statements/connections are closed (Do not wait to close them by JBoss)

  - To check this follow the suggestions by Jesper/Wolf-Dieter Fink
- Tune your thread pool(s) if you are using
- Log the number of opened connections using a bat file when you get the exceptionas this could give a rough idea
- Increase the blocking-timeout-millis (By default 30s; this is not the ideal fix)
- Increase the number of connections if and only if necessary

As per the discussion in https://developer.jboss.org/thread/223747